# Is there a way to record partital area of video using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video-processing, video-capture

I would like to record area of video with particular coordinates (in format frame[top:bottom, left:right]) with OpenCV. Parametrs CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT are not suitable for this task. Is it possible to do this during recording, without post-cutting? Maybe there is another way, with other library(Python)?

Comment: no. not possible. you have to do your own slicing. -- how about you use ffmpeg from the terminal?

Comment: Maybe there is another way, with other library(Python)? The answer is NO!